# How to do a textbox in terminal ruby applications?

Tags: ruby, textbox, terminal, rubygems

How to do a textbox in terminal ruby applications? Is there a gem for this or it can be done using pure ruby.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an ncurses implementation, see the answer you already got. Depending on your exact needs, there's also a lot of potentially interesting answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805499/is-there-a-command-line-framework-for-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Ruby 1.9.x, you can take a look at [rbcurse](https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse), a

> ruby based curses widgets: fields, buttons, textarea. menus, message boxes, tabbed panes, tables, listboxes, splitpanes, scrollpanes. Event based, MVC architecture.

The developer recently split the functionality up into

- https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse-core
- https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse-extras
- https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse-experimental

Comment: Is there a difference between  text/entry fields Textarea in this library

Comment: Yes, you can have non-editable text such as labels, or editable text in a TextArea. TextView is non-editable, scrollable text box which contains vim-like bindings for navigation.
There is also Field which is for entering one-line text such as name, address etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [tty-box](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-box) for creating flexible terminal boxes.

You can do more complex layouts of many boxes that are interlinked as well.

Comment: No worries. This is for the benefit of the Ruby devs that may still be looking for answers, especially without dependency on ncurses.